# Colocar itens SELECT Mysql Lado a Lado com Bootstrap

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Boa tarde,

Estou fazendo uma consulta num banco, para um site de imobiliária. Gostaria que esta consulta gerasse os imóveis lado a lado, e não um abaixo do outro.

Existe uma forma de fazer isso, utilizando Bootstrap? Se não, como posso fazer usando tabelas?

Segue um exemplo do código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
    <title>teste</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>


    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

        <?php
            require 'conexao.php';

            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imoveisvenda");
            while($exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        ?>

            <!-- VENDA -->
            <div class="col-md-3"> <br>
                    <img src="<?php echo "$exibe[v_imagem]";?>" class="img-responsive" alt="Casa para Venda">
                    <center><p style="margin-top:5%; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; color:#001364; padding:2%;"><?php echo "$exibe[v_imovel]";?></p>
                    <p><?php echo "$exibe[v_localizacao]";?></p>
                    <p><?php echo "$exibe[v_detalhes]";?></p>
                    <p style="font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; color:#001364; padding:2%"><?php echo "$exibe[v_valor]";?></p></center>
            </div>
            <!-- VENDA -->

        </div>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Preciso inserir mais alguma informação?

Agradeço a ajuda!

[image: Print do Problema]

Comment: Com as informações passadas fica dificil ajudar, adicione à pergunta a pagina em que você está tentando fazer essa alteração.

Comment: O que você já tem? Mesmo não estando do jeito que você gostaria, nos mostre o que tens para podermos ajudá-lo.

Comment: @Vaati, coloquei o código que estou usando, obrigado pelo alerta

Comment: da forma que vc, com col-md-3, os dados já vão ficar lado-a-lado. A menos que a resolução da tela seja pequena (em um celular, por exemplo).

Comment: @FernandoMondo Bem colocado! Agora é só ver o que ele tá aprontando com a classe `.boxhome` hehee Também tem a questão de saber se a imagem está dentro da `div` ou se existe `overflow`, o que atrapalharia.

Comment: @FernandoMondo, tirei todas as classes, pra ver se tinha alguma atrapalhando o processo. Digamos que eu "quase" cheguei lá. Ainda fica um item em cima e os outros embaixo, não lado a lado. Gostaria de mandar um print, estou tentando descobrir como... rs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galera, obrigado pelo suporte!

Resolvi essa questão da seguinte forma:

```
<div>

        <?php
            require 'conexao.php';

            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imoveisvenda");
            while($exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        ?>

            <!-- VENDA -->
            <div class="col-md-3"> <br>
                    <img src="<?php echo "$exibe[v_imagem]";?>" class="img-responsive" alt="Casa para Venda">
                    <center><p style="margin-top:5%; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; color:#001364; padding:2%;"><?php echo "$exibe[v_imovel]";?></p>
                    <p><?php echo "$exibe[v_localizacao]";?></p>
                    <p><?php echo "$exibe[v_detalhes]";?></p>
                    <p style="font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; color:#001364; padding:2%"><?php echo "$exibe[v_valor]";?></p></center>
            </div>
            <!-- VENDA -->

        <?php } ?>

    </div>
```

Simplesmente tirei a classe "container" e "row", do bootstrap, deixei apenas a classe col-md-3, e para minha surpresa, ficou lado a lado, certinho.

Mais uma vez, obrigado a todos!

Comment: mesmo que tenha funcionado, esta não é a maneira "correta" de usar o bootstrap. Segundo a documentação você deveria ter sempre um container e rows para agrupar suas cols.

Comment: Compreendo. Mas não encontrei outra forma, infelizmente. Ainda vou estudar com mais calma, se achar outra solução, posto aqui. Obrigado.